# Need help understanding several MATLAB statement

Tags: matlab, syntax

All are from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153768/matlab-to-draw-ellipse-and-ellipsoid/2155456#2155456).

What does these statement mean:

```
error(nargchk(5, 6, nargin));

plot(p(:,1), p(:,2), '.-'), axis equal
```

And what's this kinda syntax which I haven't quite often seen:

```
if nargin<6, steps = 36; end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at

```
help plot
help axis
help nargin
```

Comment: Can you explain what's the difference of `,` and `;` in `if nargin<6, steps = 36; end`?

Comment: , sequences statements, ; suppresses output

Comment: Sorry,what do you mean by `suppresses output`,can you elaborate?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f0-36861.html#f0-36866

Answer (score 2):

I hope I don't come over as too unhelpful, but have you tried:

- using Matlab's built-in help facilities to discover for yourself what the various statements mean ? or
- running any of the code ?

All the statements are Matlab intrinsics and well documented.  The use of , to separate statements on the same line is a bit unusual (I, for one, would usually put the statements on different lines in your examples), but not incorrect