# how to plot ellipse in this format?

Tags: matlab, ellipse

I would like to ask how to plot ellipse in such format:

a*x^2+b*y^2+c*x*y+d*x+e*y-1=0

I tried with `ezplot` and `contour` and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I would suggest checking out this related/potential duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153768/matlab-to-draw-ellipse-and-ellipsoid

Answer (score 0):

If you use that equation you must satisfy the relation c^2 - 4ab < 0 for it to be an ellipse.

Edit: Also specifying more clearly how it does not seem to work (what you were expecting and what happened) could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use numeric values for the parameters a through e. Then you can plot the ellipse with `ezplot`.

Answer (score 0):

see this file on the matlab file exchange:
[ellipse.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/289-ellipse-m)