# 2D Distribution Region of Interest

Tags: matlab, statistics

Given a 2D distribution. See image:
[image: scatterplot]),

How can I find the Region of Interest that contains 90% or 95% of the data in matlab?

Many thanks

Comment: What type of ROI are you looking for?  A box?  An arbitrary shape?  Circle?  Also, you show three different plots.  Are these different dimensions of the data?  What's the red and blue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ellipse around the data in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417028/ellipse-around-the-data-in-matlab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`error_ellipse`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4705-errorellipse) to obtain the required confidence region. All you need to do is give it the covariance matrix (easily obtained with `cov(D)` where `D` is matrix where each row is a mean-shifted point)

#### Sample code:

```
D = randn(1000,2);
mu = mean(D);
Dm = bsxfun(@minus,D,mu);
error_ellipse(cov(Dm),'conf',0.95,'mu',mu);
hold on;
plot(D(:,1),D(:,2),'r*');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this really helped! The source code can be found: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4705-errorellipse