# Random circles without overlap in python

Tags: python, image, numpy, geometry

I want to create datapoints which form non overlapping circle shapes; so far I was able to generate randomly distributed circles but without considering the non-overlapping feature.
How can I implement that these circles do not overlap while creating for example 2 (number_circles = 2) of them?

Comment: How many circles and how dense will you have? If the density is not too high, a simple brutal force approach (placing randomly circle one-by-one, for the new circle checking overlap with all already placed circles) should work

Comment: for the first step 2 circles without overlapping are enough; but in further stages I want to easily extend the number. 
The density is relatively high since the boundaries in x,y- direction are max = 10 and the radii are max = 2
@JanStránský

Comment: Have a look at [a matlab solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177195/non-overlapping-randomly-located-circles)

Comment: Do you need all the circles fully inside the region, or just the center inside is ok?

Answer (score 1):

Draw N centers randomly. For every center compute the distance to the nearest neighbor and assign half that distance as the radius (or a little less). This will ensure no overlap.

---

Note that you said nothing about the desired distribution of radii and this answer only fulfills the non-overlap constraint.