# Creating a movie in MATLAB with point data for a simple N-body simulation

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a simple n-body gravity simulation with 4 particles in C++. I am outputting the positions of the 4 particles to .mat files labeled "time_X.mat" (where X=1,2,3.... indicates the time-stamp) in the form of a 4x2 matrix where
i'th row indicates (x,y) cooridinates of the ith particle at time X .

Now for a *particular* time-step I am able load the .mat file into MATLAB and get a scatterplot of the points in the matrix, showing me particle positions. But I would like to create a movie out of all the .mat files / scatter-plots of the time_X.mat files which shows me the evolution of the 4 particle syestem . How should I do that in MATLAB?

Comment: Have you read the help page on animation?  http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f10-1460.html

Comment: Are you asking how to make a stand-alone movie (*.avi, *.mov, or similar), or how to animate/visualize it within Matlab?

Comment: Yes I was asking how to make a stand-alone movie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to make frames (images) of each time step of your simulation.

Since you have Cartesian coordinates, you have to convert your x and y coordinates to pixel indices, and make an image matrix from them.  See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721255/axis-coordinates-to-pixel-coordinates-matlab/7721402#7721402) to a relevant question for an example of how to do this.  You could also modify the code to make your points larger than a pixel, have shapes, etc., perhaps with `strel` or `[a,b,~] = sphere(N)`.

Once you have the frames, you can easily make an AVI file (uncompressed or MPEG) in MATLAB:

```
aviOutput = fullfile('path','to','file.avi');
aviobj = VideoWriter(aviOutput);
aviobj.Quality = 100;
aviobj.FrameRate = 24; %# arbitrary
open(aviobj);
for i=1:length(frames)
    writeVideo(aviobj,frames{i}); %# or frames(:,:,i) etc.
end
close(aviobj);
```

**Update**

The above assumes the time steps are all available.  For example:

```
files = dir('path/to/dir');
files(1:2) = []; %# . and ..
orderedfiles = cell(length(files),1);
for i=1:length(files)
   ind = sscanf(files(i).name,[name '%*[_]%u%*s']);
   orderedfiles{ind+1} = files(i).name;
end
timeSteps = zeros(numPoints,2,length(orderedfiles));
for i=1:length(orderedfiles)
    temp = load(orderedfiles(i).name);
    timeSteps(:,:,i) = temp.matrixName %# All the same name?
end
```

The code from the linked answer is written to operate on two vectors `x` and `y` with the coordinates, which you would get with `timeSteps(:,1,i)` and `timeSteps(:,2,i)`, and do for each time step.