# MATLAB How to convert axis coordinates to pixel coordinates?

Tags: image, matlab, pixel, coordinate

What is the preferred way of converting from axis coordinates (e.g. those taken in by `plot` or those output in `point1` and `point2` of `houghlines`) to pixel coordinates in an image?

I see the function [axes2pix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/axes2pix.html) in the Mathworks documentation, but it is unclear how it works. Specifically, what is the third argument? The examples just pass in `30`, but it is unclear where this value comes from. The explanations depend on a knowledge of several other functions, which I don't know.

The related question: [Axis coordinates to pixel coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7721255) suggests using `poly2mask`, which would work for a polygon, but how do I do the same thing for a single point, or a list of points?

That question also links to [Scripts to Convert Image to and from Graph Coordinates](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29598-convert-image-to-and-from-graph-coordinates), but that code threw an exception:

```
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code. It shows how to convert from axes coordinates to image pixel coordinates.

This is especially useful if you plot the image using custom XData/YData locations other than the default `1:width` and `1:height`. I am shifting by 100 and 200 pixels in the x/y directions in the example below.

```
function imageExample()
    %# RGB image
    img = imread('peppers.png');
    sz = size(img);

    %# show image
    hFig = figure();
    hAx = axes();
    image([1 sz(2)]+100, [1 sz(1)]+200, img)    %# shifted XData/YData

    %# hook-up mouse button-down event
    set(hFig, 'WindowButtonDownFcn',@mouseDown)

    function mouseDown(o,e)
        %# get current point
        p = get(hAx,'CurrentPoint');
        p = p(1,1:2);

        %# convert axes coordinates to image pixel coordinates
        %# I am also rounding to integers
        x = round( axes2pix(sz(2), [1 sz(2)], p(1)) );
        y = round( axes2pix(sz(1), [1 sz(1)], p(2)) );

        %# show (x,y) pixel in title
        title( sprintf('image pixel = (%d,%d)',x,y) )
    end
end
```

[image: screenshot]

*(note how the axis limits do not start at `(1,1)`, thus the need for `axes2pix`)*

Answer (score 0):

There may be a built-in way that I haven't heard of, but this shouldn't be hard to do from scratch...

```
set(axes_handle,'units','pixels');
pos = get(axes_handle,'position');
xlim = get(axes_handle,'xlim');
ylim = get(axes_handle,'ylim');
```

Using these values, you can convert from axes coordinates to pixels easily.

```
x_in_pixels = pos(1) + pos(3) * (x_in_axes-xlim(1))/(xlim(2)-xlim(1));
%# etc...
```

The above uses `pos(1)` as the x-offset of the axes within the figure.  If you don't care about this, don't use it.  Likewise, if you want it in screen coordinates, add the x-offset of the position obtained by `get(figure_handle,'position')`

Comment: This looks promising. However, what if I don't have an axis handle? For example, `houghlines` http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/houghlines.html takes in a binary image and returns structures containing lines with (x, y). This is the specific case I'm trying to handle. How do they do it?

Comment: Since `houghlines` natively operates on an image (2D matrix) I'd imagine that the `X,Y` pair is probably already in pixel space, since there is no figure/axes object (and thus no transformation to screen space) to account for.