# How do I plot an Ellipsoid using Matlab? by parametric equation

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to solve this problems:

Build the surf plot of the ellipsoid when `a=1`, `b=1`.5, `c=2` with:

```
z = c*(1-(x^2)/(a^2)-(y^2)/(b^2))^0.5;
```

Use the coordinate transformation when (0a and `b` and 22 values of `t`.

```
x=a*cos(t);
y=b*sin(t);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [draw ellipse and ellipsoid in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153768/draw-ellipse-and-ellipsoid-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 1;
b = 0.5;
c = 2;
t = linspace(0,2*pi,22);
p = linspace(0,pi,22);
[T,P] = meshgrid(t,p);
x = a*cos(T).*cos(P);
y = b*cos(T).*sin(P);
z = c*sin(T);
figure,surf(x,y,z)
```

This solution uses the parameterization for the ellipsoid. `0<=t<=2*pi` and `0<=p<=pi`

```
x = acos(t)cos(p)
y = bcos(t)sin(p)
z = cos(t)
```

Comment: Do you have to use the explicit formula? Here is a solution using the parameterization.