# Obtaining the best ellipse fit of an irregular shape

Tags: matlab, shapes, ellipse

Say that we have an irregular shape. How can we obtain the best `ellipse` fit of such shape? Does `regionprops` work for that? If so, can you kindly guide me on that?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add examples of those ellipses please.

Comment: If you want to use regionprops, those parameters could be the way to go: Centroid , MajorAxisLength , MinorAxisLength , Orientation

Answer (score 2):

Ok here is a bit of code to get you started. This is by no means perfect but it was fun doing it and I hope it will help you. The most important part of the code was actually written by @Amro in this great answer: [check me!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153768/draw-ellipse-and-ellipsoid-in-matlab). I incorporated Amro's code to plot the ellipse (Thanks Amro!).

As I mentioned in my comment, you can use regionprops with a couple of parameters to estimate an ellipse that fit some shape. The names are self-explanatory and can be used to describe an ellipse. Here is my dummy shape which looks like a potato:

[image]

The parameters we will use in `regionprops` are:

- `'Centroid'`
- `'MajorAxisLength'`
- `'MinorAxisLength'`
- `'Orientation'` and
- `'PixelList'`

Pixel list is used to plot the original shape of the image. Quick and dirty way to see how good is the fit.

So here is the code:

1) Read the image, convert it to black and white (i.e. binary) and apply regionprops:

```
clear all
clc

A = im2bw(imread('DummyEllipse.jpg'));

s = regionprops(A,'Centroid','MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength','Orientation','PixelList')
```

2) Recover the parameters from the s structure. Note that I access the 2nd element from the structure since the 1st one corresponds to the edges of the plotting area (I don't know how to call it sorry).:

```
PixList = s(2).PixelList;

x = s(2).Centroid(1);
y = s(2).Centroid(2);
a = s(2).MajorAxisLength/2;
b = s(2).MinorAxisLength/2;
angle = s(2).Orientation;
steps = 50;
```

3) Provide these parameters to Amro code to compute the ellipse:

```
%#  @param x     X coordinate
%#  @param y     Y coordinate
%#  @param a     Semimajor axis
%#  @param b     Semiminor axis
%#  @param angle Angle of the ellipse (in degrees)

beta = angle * (pi / 180);
sinbeta = sin(beta);
cosbeta = cos(beta);

alpha = linspace(0, 360, steps)' .* (pi / 180);
sinalpha = sin(alpha);
cosalpha = cos(alpha);

X = x + (a * cosalpha * cosbeta - b * sinalpha * sinbeta);
Y = y + (a * cosalpha * sinbeta + b * sinalpha * cosbeta);
```

4) Plot the results:

```
figure

plot(PixList(:,1),rot90(PixList(:,2),2),'-r') % flip the y coordinates because indexing in Matlab starts form the top of the image.
hold on
plot(X,Y,'k','LineWidth',2)

hold off
```

which gives me this:

[image]

So it's not perfect but hopefully it will help you get started.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I just got an error with this line: `PixList = s(2).PixelList;`, mentioning that: `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`. Why is that? Thanks

Comment: Oh in that case you want to use s(1).PixelList and s(1).Centroid (etc.) instead of s(2) as I wrote above. In my case regionprops outputs 2 "regions", including the actual boundaries of the figure in position 1, so I use 2 as an index. If you get that error the figure boundaries are probably not considered and this the size of the structure s is 1 instead of 2 as in my case. I'll check into that to see how come it's like that, but that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Benoit_11 for your kind support. The issue I'm having now is that I get a blank screen for "figure". Also, I want to mention that, I want such ellipse to show on the same image, and not as a separate plot.